# Scala - Domain Objects with lots of fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dao, dto

This might be a stupid question but I am relatively new to Scala so please bear with me. I am trying to model a domain object for a Spark job in Scala, which reflects the data structure of the source record and contains more than 100 fields. I am trying to figure out the best way to model this as I don't feel comfortable simply adding all the fields to a single case class. I thought about grouping closely associated fields into nested case classes but then I read in a few places that nesting case classes is not recommended. I would appreciate some input on what would be the best approach.

Edit: In response to Alvaro's comments:

So in essence we are saying that this is not recommended:

```
case class Product(name: String,
                   desc: String,
                   productGroup: String) {


  case class ProductPack(packType: String,
                         packQuantity: Int,
                         packQuantityUnit: String,
                         packUnitPrice: Float)
}
```

While this would be fine:

```
case class Product(name: String,
                   desc: String,
                   productGroup: String,
                   productPack: ProductPack) {


}

case class ProductPack(packType: String,
                       packQuantity: Int,
                       packQuantityUnit: String,
                       packUnitPrice: Float) {

}
```

Comment: Where did you read that nesting case classes is not recommended?

Comment: This is one of the places where I read it [here](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/2-language-rules.md#217-should-not-define-case-classes-nested-in-other-classes)

Comment: That guide is discouraging the **definition** of case class inside other case classes (nested classes). But having properties of a case class **reference** other case classes (defined outside of the class) is fine.

Comment: If you provide some actual code, maybe a class with several of the properties we can probably provide more relevant help.

Comment: If you need to add more than 22 fields to a single case class, read this: https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/10/11/twenty-two.html

Answer (score 2):

Your update is correct.

Another alternative: If a case class mostly makes sense in the context of another concept, sometimes I define the case class inside a companion to the concept:

```
case class Product(
  name: String,
  desc: String,
  productGroup: String
  productPack: Product.Pack
) 

object Product {
  case class Pack(
    packType: String,
    packQuantity: Int,
    packQuantityUnit: String,
    packUnitPrice: Float
  )
}
```

That should also be fine. The class is contained in an object, but it is not "nested" in the `Product` class.

Comment: Thanks for the input. A case class inside a companion object looks much cleaner